# Selective of Cono Sur 2012

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> There are 16 people sitting around a round table. They all get up and
>   sit down again so that each person sits in the same place where he was
>   or in a neighboring place (next to) where he was. 
>   Determine how many
>   distributions of the 16 people meet these requirements.

You can't use the calculator.

My reasoning:
If two people move to the same direction then all of the people move one spot to the same direction. There are 2 such premutation, left and right.
Two person can interchange their places.
There can be a maximum of 8 such interchanges. The rest of the people don't move from their spot.

Comment: Do you know how to solve any simpler similar problems (counting how many permutations of a given set have a given property)?

Comment: Think on one of those 16 people. And think where he/she could seat. How does it affect the others 15? (The answer may surprise you...!)

Answer (score 1):

Consider two consecutive people, $A$ and $B$, with $A$ on the left of $B$.

If they both move to the left, then the place of $B$ can only be taken by the one who was originally on the right of $B$ (call him $C$), hence $C$ also move to the left. But then the place of $C$ can only be taken by the one who was originally on the right of $C$ (call him $D$), hence $D$ also move to the left.

This argument continues and the conclusion is that everyone moves to the left.

Similarly, if $A$ and $B$ both move to the right, then everyone moves to the right.

---

Hence if we are not in the above two cases (i.e. everyone moves in the same direction), then there can only be "local changes", i.e. two consecutive people change their places.

To find out how many possibilities in this case, note that it's the same as asking in how many different ways can one choose any number of integers from $1$ to $n$, so that the difference of any two numbers is at least $2$ and the integers $1$ and $n$ are not both chosen. Let $G_n$ denote the answer to this problem. We are looking for $G_{16}$.

If we let $T_n$ be the above number of different ways, but without the requirement that $1$ and $n$ are not both chosen, then by considering whether $1$ is chosen, we get $T_n = T_{n - 1} + T_{n - 2}$. Together with $T_0 = 1$ and $T_1 = 2$, we get $T_n = F_{n + 2}$, where $F_n$ is the [Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

Now for the numbers $G_n$, we separate three cases:
1. the number $1$ is chosen, then the numbers $2$ and $n$ cannot be chosen, and for the rest we have $T_{n - 3}$ different ways;
2. the number $1$ is not chose, then we have $T_{n - 1}$ different ways.

Therefore $G_n = T_{n - 3} + T_{n - 1} = F_{n - 1} + F_{n + 1} = L_n$, where $L_n$ is the [Lucas number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number).

And our final answer is $G_{16} + 2 = 2209$.

---

To calculate $G_{16}$ without using a calculator, just use the recurrence relation $G_n = G_{n - 1} + G_{n - 2}$ with initial values $G_0 = 2$ and $G_1 = 1$.